# Blank mail PHP undefined index on $_POST

Tags: php, email, variables, post

I have a problem with contact form. When I send it I got the blank mail with no sender and messag etc. I've changed code many times but it still sends blank mail. This is HTML code:

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact" action="contact.php" method="post">
    <input class="contact-input white-input" type="text" required="" name="contact-names" placeholder="Ime in priimek*" required />
    <input class="contact-input white-input" type="email" required="" name="contact-email" placeholder="Elektronski naslov*" required />
    <font color="white" style="display: table;">Nagradne igre:</font>
    <select id="izbira" name="paket" style="display:table;">
        <option value="">Izberite paket...</option>
        <option value="Osnovnipaket">Osnovni paket (250€ + DDV)</option>
        <option value="Standardnipaket">Standardni paket (800€ + DDV)</option>
        <option value="Premiumpaket">Premium paket (999€ + DDV)</option>
    </select>
    <br><font color="white" style="display: table;">Nabiranje oboževalcev</font><br>
    <select id="izbirao" name="paketo" style="display:table;">
        <option value="">Izberite paket...</option>
        <option value="Osnovnipaket">Osnovni paket (250€ + DDV)</option>
        <option value="Standardnipaket">Standardni paket (800€ + DDV)</option>
        <option value="Premiumpaket">Premium paket (999€ + DDV)</option>
    </select>
    <textarea class="contact-commnent white-input" rows="2" cols="20" name="contact_message" placeholder="Vaše sporočilo..."></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Pošlji" name="submit" id="submit-button" class="contact-submit" style="display:block;" />
</form>
```

and this is contact.php code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST["contact-email"])) { $email = $_POST["contact-email"]; }
    if (isset($_POST["contact-names"])) { $ime = $_POST["contact-names"]; }
    if (isset($_POST["paket"])) { $paket = $_POST["paket"]; }
    if (isset($_POST["paketo"])) { $paketobozevalci = $_POST["paketo"]; }
    if (isset($_POST["contact_message"])) { $test = $_POST["contact_message"]; }
    $sporocilo = "Paket nagradna igra: $paket". "Paket oboževalci: $paketobozevalci". "Sporočilo: $test";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '. $email .'' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email ."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $subject = "Kontaktni obrazec";
    $poslji = mail("mariomail22@gmail.com",$subject,$sporocilo,$headers);
    if ($poslji)
    {
        echo '<style>.contact_success_box {display:block;}</style>';
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the undefined index?

Comment: You can always `print_r($_POST)` and the variables in your script to check that everything is being set as it should be.

Comment: Since you're using a non-defiled variable named `$paket` and have error reporting on, i expect you're getting an error.

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: contact-names
  PHP Notice:  Undefined index: contact-email 
  PHP Notice:  Undefined index: paket
  PHP Notice:  Undefined index: paketo
  PHP Notice:  Undefined index: contact_message

No it's not just $paket i've changed it and it still doesn't work

Comment: just do print_r($_POST) once, and check whether you are getting values or not

Comment: I don't see a problem, except a property thingy `required=""` and `required` are used two times; merge them like `required="required"`

Comment: @Khushboo This is what i get:
Array ( [contact-names] => mario [contact-email] => masd@mail.com [paket] => Osnovnipaket [paketo] => Standardnipaket [contact_message] => sadsad [submit] => Po�lji )
AND this is what i got in gmail: [link]http://pokit.org/get/img/7764101031274f409fee5534aaede8d8.png[/link]
vlzvl: I don't think thats problem i removed required paramater and still doesn't work

Comment: Regardless the weird undefined (they should work since the array posted fits your code), change the `$packet` in your `$sporocilo` variable to `$paketnagrada` since this is what you set above.

Comment: @vlzvl i've changed that also and didn't work. Is this server problem? php.ini or something else ?

Comment: I can't think why you're getting these undefined warnings, you _shouldn't_. From there the problem starts but have no idea why because in fact your array holds the right information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$paket** is not set anywhere.

You can set all the variables in the beginning of the code. That way they are all set to something and its easier for you to se what variables are used in your code.

Also you can try cleaning up your code a bit, its hard to read the code when its so packed.

And when you get a error message with line number you can more easily find the problem when there is not so much code on each line.

And give a error message when the mail() funktion fails, not just a succes message.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$mailto = "user@example.com";
$email = "";
$ime = "";
$paket = "";
$paketobozevalci = "";
$test = "";
$sporocilo = "";
$headers = "";
$subject = "Kontaktni obrazec";
$poslji = null;
$succes = '<style>.contact_success_box {display:block;}</style>';
$failure = '<style>.contact_failure_box {display:block;}</style>';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    if (isset($_POST["contact-email"])) {

        $email = $_POST["contact-email"];

    }

    if (isset($_POST["contact-names"])) {

        $ime = $_POST["contact-names"];

    }

    if (isset($_POST["paket"])) {

        $paket = $_POST["paket"];

    }

    if (isset($_POST["paketo"])) {

        $paketobozevalci = $_POST["paketo"];

    }

    if (isset($_POST["contact_message"])) {

        $test = $_POST["contact_message"];

    }

    $sporocilo .= "Paket nagradna igra: $paket";
    $sporocilo .= "Paket oboževalci: $paketobozevalci";
    $sporocilo .= "Sporočilo: $test";

    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $poslji = mail($mailto, $subject, $sporocilo, $headers);

    if ($poslji) {

        echo $succes;

    } else {

        echo $failure;

    }

}
```